# Adwords Scripts Can't find With Ids Function

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I am working on a AdWords Script for managing sitelinks on adGroup Level.
However I ran into a problem selecting sitelinks by ID.
It keeps giving the error:

TypeError: Cannot find function withIds in object [AdGroupSitelinkSelector]. (line 82)

I am running the following code:

```
function deleteSitelinks(deleteArray, adGroup){
  Logger.log(adGroup);
  for(var i = 0; i < deleteArray.length; i++){
    var sitelink = adGroup.extensions()
    .sitelinks()
    .withIds([deleteArray[i]])
    .get()
    .next();

    adGroup.removeSitelink(sitelink);
  }
}
```

I am aware that is not yet "perfect" and I will clean it up.
I have tried using the exact examples from the AdWords Reference with no success (https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_adgroupsitelinkselector#arguments_8)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Awnser was that adGroup should be replaced by AdWordsApp. 
Correct Code:

```
function deleteSitelinks(deleteArray, adGroup){
  Logger.log(adGroup);
  for(var i = 0; i < deleteArray.length; i++){
    var sitelink = AdWordsApp.extensions()
    .sitelinks()
    .withIds([deleteArray[i]])
    .get()
    .next();

    adGroup.removeSitelink(sitelink);
  }
}
```